# force div to fill specified area?

Tags: css, dom, html

what's the best way to force `DIV` to fill specified width?
I have the following code that generates and assign width to `DIV`:

```
function createLabel(str) {
        var textDiv = document.createElement('div');
        textDiv.style.width = '200px';
        textDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        textDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
        return textDiv;
}
```

I want created DIV's to have the same width, whatever text length is.

[alt text http://j.imagehost.org/0613/show-case.png](http://j.imagehost.org/0613/show-case.png)

Comment: If you set the width to a specific value in PX, it should always have the same width. Also you JavaScript looks good. So where is the problem with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might run into trouble specifying both a width and `display = 'inline'`. The width won't have any effect. You'll need to keep the default display mode for a `div` element, i.e. `block`. If you need other elements at the same horizontal position, you'll need to use `float` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width : x%">
```

x= numeric value

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the CSS `width` property, paying attention to the box model problem. Unless there is some specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Giving it a `width` attribute?

e.g.

```
<div style="width: 300px">
```

or do you mean something else? In that case, please elaborate on your question.